# How to set thread priority of a coroutine dispatcher in Kotlin Native

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-native

I'm using coroutines in my multiplatform (android + iOS) application. To be able to use multithreaded coroutines, I'm using [native-mt](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/native-mt) builds. So now I need to create a `CoroutineDispatcher` which runs on a hight priority thread. On android I'm doing it like this

```
val thread = HandlerThread("myThread", -20).also {
    it.start()
}
val highPriorityDispatcher = Handler(thread.looper).asCoroutineDispatcher()
```

Is there a way to create a similar hight-priority dispatcher on iOS?

First what I tried is to create a new dispatcher using [newSingleThreadContext](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/new-single-thread-context.html). In k/n the resulting dispatcher exposes its [Worker](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.native.concurrent/-worker/), but I have not found any ways to set worker priority.
Also I tried to raise thread priority with the [setThreadPriority](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsthread/1407523-setthreadpriority) method:

```
val highPriorityDispatcher = newSingleThreadContext("myThread").also {
    scope.launch(it){
        NSThread.setThreadPriority(1.0)
    }
}
```

But it did not seem to have the proper effect.

I'm thinking about writing a custom dispatcher using [dispatch_queue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatch_queue), but it seems to be a non-trivial task. So any help to find an easier way to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, actually it seems I was wrong.

```
val highPriorityDispatcher = newSingleThreadContext("myThread").also {
    scope.launch(it){
        NSThread.setThreadPriority(1.0)
    }
}
```

does the job and actually changes the priority, confirmed in the iOS profiler.
At the end I also added

```
  pthread_set_qos_class_self_np(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0)
```

call to set the QoS. I used the `pthread` version, because [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/PrioritizeWorkWithQoS.html) it says that

> NSThread possesses a qualityOfService property, of type
> NSQualityOfService. This class will not infer a QoS based on the
> context of its execution, so the value of this property may only be
> changed before the thread has started. Reading the qualityOfService of
> a thread at any time provides its current value.